# Write urdu in notepad file using matlab

Tags: matlab, unicode, utf-8

I have a Urdu Optical character Recognition. When I convert my image text to Unicode and write it in notepad file it shows like "ÌÇ   Ûã   ˜Ç  äíÇ   ÝÑ " not in urdu language. Here is my code

```
disp(native2unicode(rst))
f = fopen('temp.txt', 'w', 'native', 'UTF-8');
s = char(native2unicode(rst));
fprintf(f, ' %s.\r\n', s);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: I presume that notepad doesn't recognise UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 1):

The following code runs fine on my system. Maybe the added 'UTF-8' parameter helped?

```
rst='اردو‎';
disp(native2unicode(rst,'UTF-8'))
s = char(native2unicode(rst,'UTF-8'));
f = fopen('temp.txt', 'w', 'native', 'UTF-8');
fprintf(f, ' %s.\r\n', s);
fclose(f);
```

[image]